# Polynomial division problem 132

Tags: polynomials

Find $a$ and $b$  so $ h(x) = anx^n - b(n + 1)x^{n-1} + x + 2 $ is divisible by $ x^2 -3x+2$.

I know $ h(1) = h(2) = 0 $ but what do I do with $n$

Answer (score 0):

It works if and only if both $1$ and $2$ are roots of $h(x).$

Comment: So $h(1)$ and $h(2)$ are equal to $0$ but I don't get what I'm supposed to do with $n$

Comment: Setting x= 1 you have an+ b(n+ 1)+ 1+ 2= an+ b(n+1)+ 3= 0.  Setting x= 2, an(2^n)+ b(n+1)(2^(n)/2)+ 2+ 2= 2^n(an+ b(n+1)/2)+ 4= 0.

Answer (score 0):

It helps a lot to realize that $x^2- 3x+ 2= (x- 1)(x- 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

One of the root is $1$:
$$an-b(n+1)+3=0$$
Another root is $2$:
$$an2^n-b(n+1)2^{n-1}+4=0$$

Mutiply the first equation by $2^n$:

$$an2^n-b(n+1)2^n+3(2^n)=0$$

Compare the second and third equations:

$$b(n+1)2^{n-1}+(4-3(2^n))=0$$

$$b=\frac{3(2^n)-4}{(n+1)2^{n-1}}$$

Recovering $a$ is left as an exercice. $a$ and $b$ are functions of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$h(x) 
= anx^n - b(n + 1)x^{n-1} + x + 2
$,
then
$h(1) = an-b(n+1)+3$
and
$h(2) = an2^n-b(n+1)2^{n-1}+4
$.

If $h(1) = 0$
then
$b(n+1) = an+3
$.

If $h(2) = 0$
then

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=an2^n-b(n+1)2^{n-1}+4\\
&=an2^n-(an+3)2^{n-1}+4\\
&=an(2^n-2^{n-1})-3\cdot 2^{n-1}+4\\
&=an2^{n-1}-3\cdot 2^{n-1}+4\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$an 
= 3-\frac{4}{2^{n-1}}
= 3-\frac{1}{2^{n-3}}
$
or
$a = \frac{3}{n}-\frac{1}{n2^{n-3}}
$.

$b$ can then
be gotten from $a$.